# How to Access Reduce Motion setting in an app

Tags: ios, xamarin.forms, xamarin.ios, accessibility

I would like to detect whether `Reduce Motion` is enabled on a device to prevent any animations from running inside my Xamarin.Forms application.

[image: reduce motion]

I fully suspect I would need to write some platform specific code in order to detect this setting if it is even possible. I am struggling to find any resources on this topic though. Does anyone know if it is possible and if so how to go about accessing this information?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check the [IsReducedMotionEnabled](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/uikit.uiaccessibility.isreducemotionenabled?view=xamarin-ios-sdk-12) property of `UIAccessibility`

Comment: That is exactly what I needed thanks!